# Can two new and one old mobile phones be taken to India?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports, international-travel, airport-security

I am an Indian residing in Italy. Am I allowed to take two new mobile phones purchased in Italy along with the one I use to India? Can someone get me the rules/law about the gadgets? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  But you'll have to declare them at Customs when you return, and you'll likely have to pay tax and duty on them.